# Recursion: How do I keep a changing variable in a for-loop from changing during recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

I have a for-loop within a recursive function. The index i in my code changes every time a for-loop completes, however it resets when the recursion starts.
Is it possible to keep the value saved via another variable or anything of that sort? I need a variable that keeps the 'i' value of the first recursion step (or rather the 'i' value that I have before any recursion starts). 
My actual code seems rather complicated so I just pasted a sample code to explain my problem.

I have tried using other variables, also global variables. Unfortunately they also change whenever the recursion happens because I need to save the 'i' value to them somehow.

```
   int array[2][10];
   void function(){
      int x = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         //Something happens here... (The base cases are in here)
         for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            //Something happens here...(More base cases are in here)
            array[0][x] += i; //When function() starts, i is 0. I need it to 
                              //remain 0, while it
                              //runs through all the recursion steps (limited 
                              //by a recursion counter).
                              //After the recursion returns to the first level, 
                              //the for loop will continue.
                              //'i' will be 1 and then I need this value to 
                              //stay the same throughout all the
                              //recursion steps once again. How do I do that?
            //Recursion
            function();
         }
      }
   }
```

I wanted 'i' to stay the same but instead it is reset everytime the recursion restarts the for-loop.

Comment: You could pass `i` to the recursive call and start from it maybe.

Comment: To directly answer your question - you can make it `static`. But I think the real answer would be to fix you algorithm to eliminate the need in this workaround..

Comment: Normally, a recursive function has arguments to help it make progress towards the solution. No arguments means using global variables to control progress. Your function, therefore, is misdesigned. You should have one or more base cases that can be resolved without recursion, plus one or more other cases that invoke the function with arguments to make progress towards one of the base cases. For example — Ackermann's Function: `uint64_t ackermann(uint64_t m, uint64_t n) { if (m == 0) return n + 1; else if (n == 0) return(ackermann(m-1, 1)); else return(ackermann(m-1, ackermann(m, n-1))); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost sounds like you might want to move the `i` loop out of `function`, and pass it in.

E.g., if you had something like:

```
void someOtherFunction()
{
    function();
}
void function(){
  int x = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     //Something happens here...
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        //Something happens here...
        array[0][x] += i;
        //Recursion
        function();
     }
  }
}
```

You might change it to:

```
void someOtherFunction()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        function(i);
}
void function(int i){
  int x = 1;
 //Something happens here...
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    //Something happens here...
    array[0][x] += i; 
    //Recursion
    function(i);
  }
}
```

with perhaps a better, more descriptive name for `i` in this case.